# Formatting MySQL long text to Date

Tags: mysql

I am working with a MySQL Database where the data that I need is in a single column that is formatted as `longtext`.  I am pulling the data out of the table with the following query.  I need to format the `Date` column as a Date Colum in the following format `mm-dd-yy` so that the front end Database utility can filter by date or date range.

```
SELECT entry_id,

GROUP_CONCAT(IF(field_id='fld_5076430', value,'') SEPARATOR '') AS user,

GROUP_CONCAT(IF(field_id='fld_8768091', value,'') SEPARATOR '') AS first,

GROUP_CONCAT(IF(field_id='fld_9970286', value,'') SEPARATOR '') AS last,

GROUP_CONCAT(IF(field_id='fld_6009157', value,'') SEPARATOR '') AS date,

GROUP_CONCAT(IF(field_id='fld_5105414', value,'') SEPARATOR '') AS event,

GROUP_CONCAT(IF(field_id='fld_7723931', value,'') SEPARATOR '') AS unit,

GROUP_CONCAT(IF(field_id='fld_1521970', value,'') SEPARATOR '') AS work,

GROUP_CONCAT(IF(field_id='fld_4590434', value,'') SEPARATOR '') AS hours

FROM kcdte_cf_form_entry_values

GROUP BY entry_id;
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Show example input data, current result, and desired result. This is very incomplete right now. How can we tell you how to convert `fld_6009157` to a specific format of date as text, when we don't know what `fld_6009157` contains? Anyway: The front-end should just receive a properly typed date value and do its own conversion; it should not be the responsibility of the DBMS to format it in some specific way. If you can, you should cast to date on the DBMS side, then have the frontend work with that date, not any (re)formatted text version of it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Without more information, you could simply use:

`STR_TO_DATE("string", "%M %d %Y")`

Comment: By my reading of the OP, this is converting in the wrong direction... They have a string but need to convert it to another format of string. Anyway, your format string is off: they want the components separated by hyphens, not spaces - and they want the year to have 2 digits, not 4.

Comment: This is the answer that finally did what I needed to do.